# How do concatenate a string with a token inside a Splunk query?

Tags: xml, splunk

I wanted to concatenate a token with a string inside a query. How should I accomplish this? For example, I have this token, $foo$ (Lets say this equals “foo” for this example) and a string “bar” and I want to combine them together to represent sourcetype=“foobar” inside my query search, how can I do that? I tried using
`eval sourcetype=concat($foo$, “bar”)`
But it didn’t work (I’m assuming because i tried this expression in the middle of a query,
`<query> index=some_dataset eval sourcetype=concat($foo$, “bar”) </query>`
Is there a way to do this inside a query?

I wanted to also add that this is for a dashboard

Answer (score 2):

The `eval` command can't go before the first `|`.  Nor can you use the concatenation operator (`.`) or the `strcat` function there.

Try setting a new token after $foo$ is defined.

```
<input token="foo" type="whatever">
   ...
   <change>
     <set token="foobar">$foo$bar</set>
   </change>
</input>
...
<query>index=some_dataset sourcetype=$foobar$</query>
```

Another option is a less-efficient query that computes the sourcetype before searching for it.

```
<query>index=some_dataset | eval st=$foo|s$."bar" | where sourcetype=st</query>
```

Comment: I wanted to keep the same token value and only combine the strings to put as a sourcetype to avoid redundancy. So for example, I want to use sourcetype=“foobar” in one query and use sourcetype=“foobarbar” in another query. Is there a way to do that by concatenating $foo$ with “bar” for one query and with “barbar” for another query in sourcetype inside the query.

Comment: I added another option to my answer.

Comment: For the second option couldn't you use a sub search so that the query isn't as inefficient (So it's not calculated for each event but instead only once)
Something like:
index=some_dataset [|makeresults 1 | eval sourcetype=$foo$."bar" | return sourcetype]

Comment: That could work, too.